# protractor test failing because ElementNotVisibleError after adding ng-if directive

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I have a web element which the test was able to find until we intruduce ng-if directive to the same. Now my test is not able to find the web element:

> ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible

```
<select ng-if="tasktypepermission" id="elementType" ng-model="task.elementType" ng-options="key as value for (key, value)  in elementTypeoptions" name="elementType" class="span3 ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid errorForInput" data-trigger="blur focusout" tasknumber-validator="" ng-disabled="task.id">
    <option class="blank" value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Val1</option>
    <option value="2">Val2</option>
    <option value="3">Val3</option>
</select>
```

The way I am accessing the element is:

```
var taskType    = function(){ return element(by.id('elementType'));};
```

What should I do to make it work? I am very new to protractor or even front end testing, so please bear with me.

Comment: What are you trying to assert? Can you post your test spec?

Comment: when your `tasktypepermission` is false then your `select` is indeed not present is the DOM. You may consider ng-show then. Or is the element not found even when `tasktypepermission` is true?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try using elementExplorer. you can try to find the requested element in multiple ways  (by class,name, ng-model).
it could make things clearer - especially if you are new to protractor.
please let me know if you don't know how to use it.